# Array in the Splunk Search

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation

```
Object{1}
  ->a{4}
     col1: "1"
     col2: "2"
     col3: "3"
     col3: "4"
  ->b[2]
     0{2}
      col5: "55"
      col6: "66"
     1{2}
       col5: "5555"
       col6: "6666"
```

I want to query in the Splunk such that I can obtain the above result
I was able to get the a-> col1,col2,col3,col4 to be displayed in table .

But wanted to check how I do it for the array :

Comment: What does the raw data look like?  Is it json or some other format?  Could you provide a mock-up of the desired output table using values from the same example of the raw data?  The notation you used does not look like a common format.

Comment: I Just wanted to show you  the visual presentation of how the data looked like from https://codebeautify.org/string-to-json-online.
Underlying data is the raw format is something like :
{"a":{"col1":"1",{col2":"2"}}}}

Comment: Splunk does not have "arrays". It has multivalue fields, but not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Splunk doesn't have arrays, but there are multivalues fields in Splunk. Here I think you can use spath.

```
| makeresults 
|eval data ="{\"a\":{\"col1\":\"1\",\"col2\":\"2\",\"col3\":\"3\",\"col4\":\"4\"},\"b\":{\"0\":{\"col5\":\"55\",\"col6\":\"66\"},\"1\":{\"col5\":\"5555\",\"col6\":\"6666\"}}}"
| spath input=data
| table a.*
```